# Datagridview Start editing on load

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I want my user to be able to begin typing when a form loads that has a datagridview loaded in the first row, first column.  No matter what I do, the user has to click into the cell to begin typing.
This is what I have tried so far in the form on load event.

```
    With dgTable
        .Focus()
        .Rows.Add(50)
        .EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter
        .CurrentCell = .Rows(0).Cells(0)
        .BeginEdit(False)

    End With
```

Can anyone tell me what I need to do?

Comment: First, you need to read [ask] and take the [tour], because you havent.  The form does not show until after all the form load code runs.  Since it is not visible, most of the UI aspects cant happen.  Code in the `Shown` event will run *after* it is displayed

Comment: how about adding the `.Focus()` at the end?

Comment: I apologize if I didn't do something right.  I went through the ask and I am still not sure what I did wrong.  Adding the .focus to the end didn't work.  I tried adding it to the activated event then tried the shown event and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dgTable.Item(0, 0).Selected = True
```

Will select the first cell and allow typing on load.
And remove .BeginEdit(false) and .CurrentCell = .Rows(0).Cells(0)

So:

```
With dgTable
    .Focus()
    .Rows.Add(50)
    .EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter      
    .Item(0, 0).Selected = True
End With
```

Comment: @clearfog1962 Please mark the answer as accepted to help people in the future. Glad it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

The load event isn't ideal, since the control isn't visible yet.  Try using the EditProgrammatically setting and use the form's Shown override method instead:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnShown(e As EventArgs)
  MyBase.OnShown(e)
  dgTable.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically
  dgTable.BeginEdit(False)
End Sub
```